# My iPhone app crashes on Load before AppDelegate finishes Loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So I've got my awesome app, that runs perfectly on simulator or while the device is plugged in.

And then if I create an IPA and deploy it on my device, or use TestFlight, or even submit to the App Store. The app will crash most of the time when I try launching it.

The crash reports even not symbolized don't give me any information.

I've used TestFlight so that it could maybe help me figure out where the app crashes, but the app Crashes before TestFlight launches.

Here is some of my code (main.m):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "version3contentAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([version3contentAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and beginning of version3contentAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "TestFlight.h"
#import "version3contentAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootTableViewController.h"
#import "AppsFeedTableViewController.h"
#import "AboutShmoopModalViewController.h"

@implementation version3contentAppDelegate

@synthesize window, shmoopCoreData, tabBarController;



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    NSLog(@"applicationDidFinishLaunching");

    [TestFlight takeOff:@"3f3618576288d96d598646d060a4f26a_NzUyMjEyMDEyLTAzLTI2IDE3OjIxOjQzLjgyNzQwNg"];
...
```

As you can see the TestFlight code is at the beginning of the didFinishLaunching. This means that if it would crash after that, I would have a crash report on TestFlight, which I don't have.

Would anyone have any idea why this is happening ?
The project has been originally developed on an old xcode, for old iphone, currently its an xcode 3 project. But I'm programming it on XCode 4.3 with iOS 5.1 on devices.

Comment: What about putting a breakpoint on all exceptions?

Comment: But I cannot breakpoint because it crashes only if its on Adhoc, or after being submitted on Apple Store no ? (I might be wrong)

Comment: It makes no sense... deployment doesn't alter code.  How have you been getting crashes before (I guess what I mean to say is: How do you know it's crashing)?  Can you replicate it?

Comment: So I was doing patches on the apps, debugging on device, and then updating code. I guess at some point I did something wrong. Patched it to the App Store, and continued with my updates. I didn't test each versions from the App store but users started saying its crashing. Now I don't have old code. I can replicate the crash as often as I want, its crashing on the spashscreen loading. I see the spashscreen briefly, and then it crashes.

Comment: That is not specific at all!  Post the entire `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, or there's not much anyone can do.  Archives don't just break all of a sudden.

Comment: Here is my entire AppDelegate file: http://pastebin.com/N6hwGGcg but I'm pretty sure that it never even gets into the function didFinishLaunching. I'm wondering if its not a setting or something causing this problem

Comment: It does get into didFinishLaunching if it shows the splash screen.  I noticed you aren't using ARC, though.  Could it be that you are overreleasing something?  Refactor your project and see if that helps

Comment: hmm you might be right, I've got a lot of "ARC" rules errors. And some of them look like it might cause overreleasing. Thank you. It might take me a few days to restructure my code to be able to be validated by ARC. Do you want to put your comment as a quick answer ? I think this could help someone else as I've never even read about ARC while looking for my problem. And then I'll accept your answer

Comment: Of course.  When I did my refactor, I spent a good 2 hours on the sheer volume of errors I had.  Xcode knows how to fix most of them, just follow it's suggestions and it's quicker than you think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your request, here is my comment:

It does get into didFinishLaunching if it shows the splash screen. I noticed you aren't using ARC, though. Could it be that you are overreleasing something? Refactor your project and see if that helps

Answer (score 6):

If it crashes on your device then you will have a crash log to look at.

Secondly, in my experience the main cause of crashes in application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is due to loading resources that take too long to load.

iOS has a watchdog timer which watches apps and kills them if they take too long to do certain things. Loading, unloading etc. Usually it's a couple of seconds and if they take longer than that the timer kills them, assuming they are hung.

This timer is disabled for debug reasons in the simulator which is why these crashes only appear during actual device testing.

Once you have a crash log from your local device, check the code given, if it is 0x8badf00d then it is the watch dog timer killing your app. Notice the error code 8-bad-food :-)

Then you need to look at your code and move as much as possible onto a background thread so that the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method can finish asap.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a crash in TestFlight's launch itself - I just spent quite some time tracking down a very similar issue, where an AdHoc testing deployment was randomly, sometimes crashing on open, and it was specifically the `[TestFlight takeOff:...]` line that the backtrace showed it crashing on.

Get the crash logs off of the device (In all such cases where it has crashed after being at the splash screen I have had crash logs), and try using `symbolicatecrash` to translate the dump - In my case, it didn't translate anything except the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions` line that called into testflight.

Answer (score 0):

Its an problem with Xcode. If you are not using auto layout and size class, then delete launch xib file.
Crash will be resolved.